# HCL domino add entries to view externaly

Tags: lotus-domino

I have a hcl application  to whose View I want to add entries from my local pc. I have very little knowledge about HCL in genral and have been looking for a soultion for days now without any success. Maybe Im looking at the wrong places but there was little to find. All I know right now is that I will probably end up sending my local data for the entries via postman and I do have to make an agent?/method that is accessable via browser that can receive these information and make entries with them.

I was just pushed into this thing. I wouldnt mind some usefull links to build my foundation as well.

Comment: You want to add documents to a NotesDatabase. This can be done in many ways. You need to look for a training as without at least the basic understanding of Objects in Domino Applications / Databases / NSF- Files you will not be able to complete your task. [This](https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/11.0.1/basic/H_ONLINE_DESIGNER_HELP_OVERVIEW_9778_CHAP.html) could be a good starting point, and then you will want to read into [LotusScript](https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/11.0.1/basic/LSAZ_CHAPTER_2CREATING_COMPILING_AND_DEBUGGING_SCRIPTS.html)

Comment: @TorstenLink I have been reading the links you gave me and honestly I can not learn like this. You wrote there are many ways it can be done. Do you perhaps by chance have an example code of something similiar? I  imagine  what I want to do is common practice and I just dont seem to look at the right places . I would do way better at learning just by looking at a code.

Comment: This site is not the place for newbies to come looking for code examples that solve problems they don't know how to define properly for a technology that they don't know the basics about. There is 30 years worth of material out there for Domino! The reason you're not finding it is likely that you haven't even learned the vocabulary. You don't want to "make entries". You want to add documents to a database, specify a form and set item values so that the documents will be selected in a view. Use that very basic information in your research, and maybe you'll have better results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to add *documents* to a Notes/Domino *database*.
You are not very specific, it is not even clear if you want to do it programmatically. As Torsten said in his comment to your original post, there are many ways to do that.
Here are a couple:

1. Using the **Notes rich client**.
2. Through a **web browser**, accessing a **web-enabled Domino database**. This assumes the creator of the database has exposed the functionality to create documents on the web.
3. Use **COM (or Java)** to create the documents from an external scriptable application or using a programming language/platform supporting COM:
   https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/9.0.1/appdev/H_EXAMPLES_ACCESSING_THE_DOMINO_OBJECTS_THROUGH_COM.html
4. Call a **REST service** on the Domino server that will create new documents. You can write a REST service using Lotusscript, Java or XPages:
   https://www.slideshare.net/TexasSwede/break-out-of-the-box-part-2 (you can skip to slide 19)
5. Use **Domino Access Services** (DAS), a framework for adding REST services to Domino.  A DAS service is implemented in Java and deployed as an OSGi plug-in:
   https://ds-infolib.hcltechsw.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Create_your_own_Domino_REST_service_using_DAS
   and
   https://www.slideshare.net/JohnDalsgaard/engage-ug-rest-services-2015
6. Use node.js and the **Domino AppDev Pack**:  https://doc.cwpcollaboration.com/appdevpack/docs/en/homepage.html
   and
   http://www.c3ug.ca/c3ug-blog/2020/6/30/announcement-learning-the-domino-appdev-pack-a-free-course-from-c3ug

There are probably a few more ways that I am forgetting...

Before you do anything else, you need to learn more about the Domino platform, the structure of a database, and the proper terminology used in Domino. If you don't understand the basics, you will not be able to write any kind of integration with Domino.

Comment: Thanks for all the option you listed. I eventually ended up making an Action button that can import excel files